# Put info from google maps InfoWindow into HTML textbox

Tags: events, google-maps, marker

I have a map that has lots of markers pulled from a database.  Each one displays an InfoWindow with a placename and the lat and lng of the location.  I need to have the placename affiliated with a marker added to and HTML textbox on click.  I can't seem to find any tutorials on this.  Maybe someone can point me in the right direction. I am trying to learn this on my own so apologies if it is sloppily designed. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.640078, -102.669433),
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  downloadUrl("mymap.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + point;

      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}







function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {


    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

It needs to go into a simple textbox like this:

```
<input type = "text" id = "address_box" value = ""/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display that data in your HTML text box, change your bindInfoWindow function, add code in there to put the data in the text box:

```
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, name) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    document.getElementById("address_box").value = name;
  });
}
```

And add name in to the call to it:

```
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, name);
```

Comment: OK great, this is working.  How can I avoid the replacement of a single quote with the code &#39; if it exists in document.getElementById("address_box").value = name; ? I must need to escape this somehow.

Comment: That sounds like another question, it certainly requires more context than you have provided.

Comment: scratch that, I forgot I used str_replace in my php to put it there.  Removed that and it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, when the infoWindow opens, you want to display some information into the textbox?
If so, this code might help you(I hope).

```
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  var address_box = document.getElementById("address_box");
  google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, "domready", function() {

    address_box.value = infoWindow.get("Content");
  });
```